# Can I run Rails on Node?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js

According to codeschool.com node.js is a web server, not a web framework. If this is true- does it mean we can run Rails on it? Rails is a web framework, Node is a web server. Seems to make sense that we could run Rails on Node.

Comment: Why would you want this? Rails comes with it's own web server when in development mode otherwise you should deploy a rails application using [Unicorn](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/)

Comment: I'm just curious if it were possible.

Comment: In theory, everything is possible. In practice, it depends on what you'd have to do to make it happen. Have you tried to do some research on this question yourself? What are the results? On top of that even [the official NodeJS website](http://nodejs.org/) hints that it's **not a webserver**. So no, it doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: take a look at http://sailsjs.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If CodeSchool stated that node is a web server then they would be very wrong. Node is nothing but a JavaScript interpreter built on the V8 engine. Node has the capacity to use libraries and frameworks to be used as a web server; although Node itself is NOT a web server.

Rails cannot be run on Node because Rails is a Ruby framework and Node is meant specifically for JavaScript.